# Remove table background in one cell

Tags: css

Sorry if the title isn't descriptive, I didn't know how to word it. Here's the table in question.

[image: A part of a table with a white border around each cell.]

Is it possible for me to remove the white border (the background of the table) from this upper-left cell? I still want this white background between the rest of the cells, but in that upper-left I want it removed. Here's how I want it to look.

[image: The same table as before, with the left and upper white borders of the upper-left cell removed.]

My initial thought is to have some ::after pseudo-element on that cell that has some border or padding that can cover that gap between the cell and page background, but I don't know how to do that. Any ideas?

Here's the CSS on this page.

```
    body{
        background: #C3DEF2;
        font-family: Noto Sans, Roboto, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    }
    
    table{
        background: white;
        table-layout: fixed;
    }
    tr:nth-child(even){
        background: lightgray;
    }
    td{
        padding: 20px;
    }
    td.corner{ /* cell in upper-left corner */
        background: #C3DEF2;
    }
    
    .head1{ /* top row */
        text-align: center;
    }
    .head2{ /* leftmost column */
        text-align: right;
    }
    .head1, .head2{
        background: lightblue;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        font-weight: 600;
    }
```

As requested, here's some of the HTML relating to this part of the table.

```
<table id="the_table" width="100%">
<tbody>
    <tr class="head1">
        <td class="corner"></td>
        <td><a href="https://stackoverflow.com">Candidate 1</a></td>
        <td><a href="https://stackoverflow.com">Candidate 2</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="head2">Education</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="head2">Election Reform</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="head2">Environment</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="head2">Foreign Policy</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Probably more importantly, where does this border come from? It's the white background of the table, but what causes that space between the cells?

Comment: I am no expert on tables, but if you select the cell with an id, then change the border, it should solve your problem. Sorry I don't have an example, but I have don't know tables that well.

Comment: To remove the white border, try using: "border-collapse: collapse;"

Comment: I'd still like to keep the white border around the rest of the cells, just remove it on the top and left borders of the upper-left cell. "border-collapse: collapse;" would remove the border around every cell.

Comment: can you share the HTML code or part of it?

Comment: Sure thing, edited the original post to contain the HTML code of the table.

Comment: See the answer/solution below. Just change the first "td" border type to "inset" and the background color to "lightblue" in your case.

Comment: Also, if you think it resolved your issue, please approve it as the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a quick solution:

HTML:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td style="border: 1px inset white;">1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>5</td>
        <td>6</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>7</td>
        <td>8</td>
        <td>9</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

CSS:

```
table {
    margin: 20px;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
}

td {
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    text-align: center;
}

td:hover {
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

DEMO:

https://liveweave.com/7eIF6k

Comment: I hadn't considered using an inset border at all! This is perfect, thank you!